# Why doesn't minimizing squared errors with scipy's minimize give the same result as using curve_fit?

Tags: python, scipy, regression

As an example, here's my code for fitting multiexponential decays with a monoexponential decay (this doesn't produce a good fit, but it still works as an example):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize, curve_fit

lifetimes = [1e-9, 2e-9, 4e-9, 8e-9]
amplitudes = [1000, 1000, 1000, 1000]
background = 10

t = np.arange(1024)*1e-10
y = np.zeros(len(t))
for i in range(len(lifetimes)):
    y += amplitudes[i] * np.exp(-t/lifetimes[i])
y += np.random.poisson(background, len(y))

def fit_fun(t, amplitude, lifetime, background):
    return amplitude * np.exp(-t/lifetime) + background

def loss_fun(params, x, y, fit_fun, c=5):
    fit_y = fit_fun(x, *params)
    residuals = y - fit_y
    loss = np.sum(residuals**2)
    return loss

p0 = [1000, 6e-9, 10]
result = minimize(loss_fun, p0, args=(t, y, fit_fun))
params_minimize = result.x
minimize_y = fit_fun(t, *params_minimize)

params_fit, _ = curve_fit(fit_fun, t, y, p0)
fit_y = fit_fun(t, *params_fit)

plt.semilogy(t, y)
plt.semilogy(t, minimize_y)
plt.semilogy(t, fit_y)
plt.ylim([1, plt.ylim()[1]])
plt.show()
```

[Here are the resulting fits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKwL1.png) (Green was fitted with curve_fit and orange with minimize).

So, why doesn't using minimize work properly?

Also, the reason I'm doing this is that I want to implement a loss function other than least squares. If it isn't possible this way, how could I do that?

Comment: `curve_fit` and `minimize` use different solvers. You can see [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) that `curve_fit` defaults to `lm`, whereas that is not an option for [`minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html). [`scipy.optimize.least_squares`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) will probably yield same result as `curve_fit` though

Comment: @Brenlla Okay, but what can I do to implement a custom loss function? Because minimize doesn't seem to work at all even with least squares.

Comment: Just make a loss functions that returns `residuals` and pass it to `scipy.optimize.least_squares`. You only have to delete couple lines of code.

Comment: When you use `minimize`, always check `result.success` before using `result.x`.  In this case, `result.success` is False: the optimizer does not converge to a solution.  `minimize` succeeds and gives the same result as `curve_fit` if you use, for example, `method='Nelder-Mead'` or `method='Powell'`.

Comment: It is usually better to avoid `p0` from taking extremely large/small values due to lack of floating point precission. If you multiply `t`, `lifetimes` and `p0` by 1E9 your original code should work better

Comment: In addition to my last comment, you may get better convergence results if all `p0` values are within the same order of magnitude. btw, when I said to multiply `p0` by 1E9 I meant only the lifetime (`p0[1]`)